# "class_names" in export_graphviz unexpected keyword error

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, graphviz, pydot

With the following code:

```
classes = ['ham', 'spam']
dot_data = StringIO()
with open("./plots/ritesh.dot", "w") as f:
    export_graphviz(dt_old.named_steps['classifier'], out_file=f, feature_names=vocab1, class_names=classes)
```

I am getting error as unexpected keyword argument.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DecisionTree.py", line 198, in <module>
    main()
  File "DecisionTree.py", line 133, in main
    export_graphviz(dt_old.named_steps['classifier'], out_file=f, feature_names=vocab1, class_names=classes)
TypeError: export_graphviz() got an unexpected keyword argument 'class_names'
```

But it is clearly mentioned in scikit-learn doc that

```
sklearn.tree.export_graphviz(decision_tree, out_file='tree.dot', max_depth=None, feature_names=None, class_names=None, label='all', filled=False, leaves_parallel=False, impurity=True, node_ids=False, proportion=False, rotate=False, rounded=False, special_characters=False)
```

What is the cause of that TypeError?

Answer (score 7):

The version of sklearn you have installed is likely out of date with the documentation. 
If you installed sklearn with anaconda try on the command line
"conda update scikit-learn"